# tabela não é criada em mySQL

Tags: mysql, tabela-html

```
create database mbsys
default character set utf8
default collate utf8_german2_ci;
```

''essa gera normal''

```
create table PESSOA (
ID_PESSOA int (10) not null,
NOME varchar (40) not null,
CPF int (11) not null,
NASCIMENTO date not null,
SEXO enum ('M','F') not null,
constraint PK_ID_PESSOA PRIMARY KEY (ID_PESSOA),
constraint UK_CPF unique (CPF)
)default charset = utf8;
```

''essa gera normal''

```
create table ENDERECO (
ID_PESSOA int (10) not null,
RUA varchar (40) not null,
NUMERO varchar (10) not null,
CEP int (11) not null,
BAIRRO varchar (10) not null,
CIDADE varchar (10) not null,
constraint FK_ID_PESSOA foreign key (ID_PESSOA)
references PESSOA (ID_PESSOA)
)default charset = utf8;
```

''essa da o problema''

```
create table VENDA (
ID_PESSOA int (10) not null,
ID_VENDA int (10) not null,
VALOR_TOTAL decimal (8,2),
constraint PK_ID_VENDA PRIMARY KEY (ID_VENDA),
constraint FK_ID_PESSOA foreign key (ID_PESSOA)
references PESSOA (ID_PESSOA)
)default charset = utf8;
```

LOG de erro:

> ```
> > 12:05:44    create table VENDA ( ID_PESSOA int (10) not null, ID_VENDA
> > int (10) not null,  VALOR_TOTAL decimal (8,2), constraint PK_ID_VENDA
> > PRIMARY KEY (ID_VENDA), constraint FK_ID_PESSOA foreign key
> > (ID_PESSOA) references PESSOA (ID_PESSOA) )default charset =
> > utf8    Error Code: 1022. Can't write; duplicate key in table
> > 'venda' 0.375 sec
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você já criou uma constraint com o nome `FK_ID_PESSOA` na tabela `ENDERECO` , na tabela `VENDA` você tentou criar outra constraint com o mesmo nome.

Altere o código de criação da tabela `VENDA` para:

```
create table VENDA (
    ID_PESSOA int (10) not null,
    ID_VENDA int (10) not null,
    VALOR_TOTAL decimal (8,2),
    constraint PK_ID_VENDA PRIMARY KEY (ID_VENDA),
    constraint FK_ID_PESSOA2 foreign key (ID_PESSOA)
    references PESSOA (ID_PESSOA)
)default charset = utf8;
```

Nomeei para `FK_ID_PESSOA2` basta alterar para a que você desejar.

Comment: Muito obrigado não sabia dessa particularidade no oracle ele permite. Valew mesmo

Comment: Se resolveu por gentileza sinalizar a resposta como correta e resolvida ;)

Comment: como faz isso não encontrei o botão.

Comment: @LordSnow ao lado da minha pergunta tem um "0" e embaixo do zero tem um simbolo de "correto" "certo" kkkk é lá